# Class design question regarding a Server Client Game

Tags: java, server, architecture, client, software-design

I have a question regarding the class design of a game. I had already a basic set up of a Server, Client Connection and a Client.
My goal is to implement a game on top of this. The game is a index card game where the players receive a word and have to translate it. The first player which responds the correct translation receives a point.
My thoughts are to implement a game class where all the logic happens.
Here you can see my current class diagram (sorry if some of the logic isn't well drawn. I only have googled my way through class diagram design and this was the best I could do)

[my class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFM1R.png)

The server gets at the start the number of players, rounds and other variables and holds an instance of game and initializes it with the passed arguments. In the game and there all the logic happens as to chose the next term so send and checks who answers correct
My questions are :how to solve it in a proper way regarding the game sending for example the current word to translate via the broadcast function.
My first idea was to that game extends server so I can use the broadcast function of server in game. But I am not sure as the game actually isn't an instance from type server and the server holds an instance of it. Therefore it doesn't feel right regarding OOP.
My other concern is if it makes sense that the server has a list of connections and the players also have the connection to their client.Could this be solved in a more elegant way?

Can somebody please help me to have a nice and well defined Class structure?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track and have a good intuition about where to take this.

My general recommendation would be to start off with the classes having clearly defined roles and responsibilities. For example, you spoke about having the game extending server vs the server holding an instance of game. I would personally start off with latter approach because that has the opportunity for the game logic to be unrelated to the server.

I suggest enumerating the various components you think are necessary for your game and give them very clear roles. For example:

- The Server is responsible for keeping core game state and accepting incoming client (player) requests.
- The Game is responsible for core game logic.
- The Client is the user's interface to starting/initiating/interacting with the game. The Client connects to the Server.
- ... and so on.

I just made up a few descriptions above but if you go through the same exercise you'll start to see a few relationships and get a sense for how items should be related.

I think it's very important to define each with clearly separated responsibilities and not blur the lines, at least early in your design. A Game component/set-of-classes that only cares about game logic can make redesigns easier. If you make the Game and Server one-and-the-same then it will be difficult to redesign and place the Game with the client if you choose to later do a peer-to-peer system, for example. On the other hand, if the Game logic is fully encapsulated it's fine for the Server to have an instance of the Game and relay functionality back-and-forth by means of well-defined interfaces: the Game has a game related API and the Server takes care of networking and potentially serialization concerns.

After you've done an initial pass you might find you need to blur the lines a bit to be practical. That's fine. But try to resist that urge initially until you're sure what the main components will look like.

Hope that helps!